# The vs An (Comparing for most appropriate.)

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, generic-noun-phrases

> **The** average person knows 25000 words.

Vs

> **An** average person knows 25000 words.

I find the latter more appropriate, but the former is what I read almost everywhere. Does anyone have a coherent explanation to which one is *more* correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The average speaker knows 25000 words.
>
> An average speaker knows 25000 words.

Both are ways of making a generalization.

***The*** average speaker refers to the *prototypical* average speaker.

***An*** average speaker refers to a speaker selected at random, as it were, from the set of average speakers, a *representative* sample.